# Put Image View above Button - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some XML that looks like this

```
<!--
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minWidth="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailField" />
-->

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/Btn1"
    android:background="#907F0106"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/Btn2"
    android:background="#907F0106"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailField"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/emailField"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/emailField" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minWidth="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailField" />
```

I have tried it above and below but it always looks like it is partly hidden behind the buttons, as seen below

But I want a full white line going down, not one that is partly hidden behind?
[image]

Comment: can you post full code?

Comment: what you actually want??

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Aashvi I want a white line, I have the image view color as white but it appears as though it is tinted red

Comment: I can't get you... you want the ImageView `above` (your question title says so)... and you use `layout_below`?? Also, if the View you refer is already created, please get rid of the **+** sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try using view instead of ImageView

```
<View
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:background="@color/yourDesiredColor" />
```